# Bounded probability distribution wanted

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function

[Edit: this is a reformulation of the original question, based on the comments by whuber and LmnICE below]

I am looking for a bounded continuous probability density function that occupies a finite interval (ideally [0;1]) with the goal to represent the error around an estimate of a probability (referred to as $x_0$). Ideally, as the precision of the distribution approaches its lower limit, the distribution should approach a uniform distribution over the [0; 1] space.

One possibility would be the truncated normal distribution, with the mean set to the probability estimate $x_0$, 0 as the lower bound, and 1 as the upper bound (as mentioned by LmnICE).

Another choice in this context might be the beta distribution:

$
f(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}
$

Now, the way I thought about this, is that the mode of the beta distribution should be at $x_0$ and the "error" is represented by the left (range
$[0;x_0]$) and right (range $[x_0; 1]$) tail of the distribution.

The way I approached this, is as follows:

I know that the mode of the beta distribution is

$
mode = \frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+\beta-2}
$

Since I want that the $mode = x_0$, this puts a constraint on $\alpha$ an $\beta$ as follows:

$
\alpha=(n-2)x_0+1
$

$
\beta=(2-n)x_0+n-1
$

where $n=\alpha+\beta$.

In this way, I obtain a distribution with mode $x_0$ that is naturally bounded between 0 and 1, and I have to fit only a single parameter $n$.

<strike>However, with these constraints in place, the distribution cannot approach the uniform distribution to an arbitrary degree ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ cannot approach 1 at the same time), hence it fails one of my criteria.</strike>

Are there other distributions that fulfill this criterion?

Comment: Do you mean in a mathematical sense? The bounded normal distribution satisfies both properties.

Comment: Thanks, this might indeed be it. I never thought of the truncated normal distribution as a proper distribution, but it might suffice for my purposes!

Comment: I cannot make sense of these requirements: ordinarily, the precision is the reciprocal of the variance, but that is not mathematically consistent with any other part of this question.  So, ignoring that, the rest of question is clearly answered with the Beta family of distributions.  Thus, I think it is essential that you clarify what you mean by "precision" and "fails" in your post.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you take issue with. Is it the fact that the precision of a bounded distribution cannot technically become zero, i.e. technically more correct I should have written that the precision "approaches it's lower limit" instead of "goes to zero"?

Comment: Re your edit: one answer is the Beta family with its parameters restricted to be $1$ or greater.  Thus, once again, I cannot understand the sense in which you write "the Beta distribution fails."  Perhaps explaining what you mean by that will help make your question answerable.

Comment: At least in my case, setting all parameters >=1 implies a lower bound on the precision of the Beta distribution, which prevents it from becoming anything close to a uniform distribution. I'm not sure whether this is a general property of the beta distribution or whether my case is special. If it is a general property, then this is perhaps the clarification that is necessary? I.e. that the distribution should be able to approach a uniform distribution with an arbitrarily small deviation? If my case (which involves additional constraints) is special, then I might have to detail these constraints

Comment: You must be using a different Beta distribution then everyone else then, because with [the conventional definition,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) Beta$(1,1)$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1].$  It's unclear what you mean by "with arbitrarily small deviation," because there is only one uniform distribution on $[0,1]$--there aren't any others.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Your conclusion is incorrect: the Beta still fulfills all your requirements. Indeed, the family of Beta$(\alpha,1+(\alpha-1)(1/x_0-1))$ distributions with common mode $x_0$ approaches the uniform distribution as $\alpha\to 1.$

Comment: You're right, I updated the question accordingly, once again.